# What priority should i set for notification music app?

Tags: android

I'm writing music app. And there is priority in Notification object. So what priority should i set for notification music app?

Comment: I'm getting down votes because I don't added any code am I right?

Comment: You didn't added any code, you didnt told as anything that you already tried, so it does not look good...

Comment: @404notfound Thanks, I will remember for the next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) you can see that:

`PRIORITY_DEFAULT`: Default notification priority;

`PRIORITY_HIGH`:    Higher priority, for more important notifications or alerts;

`PRIORITY_LOW`: Lower priority, for items that are less important;

`PRIORITY_MAX`: Highest priority, for your application's most important items that require the user's prompt attention or input;

`PRIORITY_MIN`: Lowest priority; these items might not be shown to the user except under special circumstances, such as detailed notification logs.

Based on the above information, I would suggest you to use `PRIORITY_DEFAULT`